# Paginator->sort() using joined model does not work

Tags: join, pagination, cakephp-2.2

My models association chain:

```
ArchitectPurchase belongsTo ArchitectProfile belongsTo User
```

My action:

```
    $this->ArchitectPurchase->recursive = -1;
    $this->ArchitectPurchase->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

    $this->paginate['joins'] = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'architect_profiles',
            'alias' => 'ArchitectProfileJoin',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'ArchitectProfileJoin.id = ArchitectPurchase.architect_profile_id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id = ArchitectProfileJoin.user_id'
            )
        )           
    );

    $this->paginate['order'] = 'User.name DESC';

    $this->paginate['contain'] = array(
        'ArchitectProfile' => array(
            'fields' => array('ArchitectProfile.id'),
            'User' => array(
                'fields' => array('User.name')
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('architectPurchases', $this->paginate());
```

This action works fine, ordering the results by User.name DESC. But when I use the link created with

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('User.name')
```

in my view, it does not work!

Looking at the core files, I found that the validateSort method of the PaginatorComponent was the problem:

```
            if ($object->hasField($field)) {
                $order[$alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            } elseif ($object->hasField($key, true)) {
                $order[$field] = $value;
            } elseif (isset($object->{$alias}) && $object->{$alias}->hasField($field, true)) {
                $order[$alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            }
```

As the User model is not directly associated with the ArchitectPurchase model, I get

```
$order = array()
```

instead of

```
$order = array('User.name' => 'asc')
```

I tried to use the $whitelist parameter, but still not working...

So I had to hack the core (noooo!!!), commenting from line 345 to 363 to make it work.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a 2.2.1 issue?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for posting this, I was actually having the same issue and with your insight of the problem I was able to solve it.

I posted a [ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3569-paginatorcomponent-not-sorting-properly) on the issue tracker of CakePHP if anyone is interested, but basically they said it won't be fixed and offered two recommendations to bypass the problem.

The way I fixed it is I forced the model to be related with the one that has the field I'm interested in order by.

Comment: Not an answer; this should be posted as a comment instead.

Comment: I can't comment his post. I think it is because I need a minimum of reputation and I have zero.